# Updated ruby, then gemsets via rvm upgrade, but .rvmrc files?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm not sure if my workflow is off, or if I'm using rvm gemsets entirely wrong, but here's how I upgraded to the latest patch level in Ruby today [327].

Updated ruby via rvm install.
Ran rvm upgrade and upgraded everything
Selected yes, when asked during rvm upgrade to delete old ruby.

So, then I noticed that my .rvmrc files in my apps were trying to load the old gemset that now doesn't exist.  I manually updated each .rvmrc file with the new gemset from the rvm upgrade.

All is well, but my questions:

1. Should I have kept my prior version of ruby installed just in case?
2. Is manually updating each .rvmrc the right thing to do?
3. Should I be creating gemsets for each app, or should I really just use gemsets to manage ruby versions for different required environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Patches don't really change much thing that can accidentally break your code. Keep just major versions. (1.8.7, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, etc)

2- This way is the fastest and simplest way. It works flawless and really don't have any problem.

3- Gemsets are good for organization purposes. I really like to have on for each project, but i guess i and kind of a control freak, so i believe it is personal taste.

Comment: In the `.rvmrc` file, specify only the major version. Eg: `rvm use 1.9.3@<gemset name>`; looks like you were using `rvm use 1.9.3-p286@<gemset name>`.

Comment: Exactly - it was referencing the older patch of Ruby in there.  After manually updating each one of my apps, all is well.